# In Visual Basic forms confirm exit using message box

Tags: vb.net, forms, button

I have a basic me.close() button. I need to add a second step confirmation if it is pressed using a message box pop up.

Comment: Look into the `FormClosing` event.

Comment: Or something like: `if MessageBox.Show(me, "Really?","Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question = DialogResult.Yes) then me.Close() return end if` (in the Button's `Click` handler). With `Forms` you mean Windows Forms, right?

Comment: @Jimi, fair call. I guess the question is whether you want the same prompt if the user tries to close the form any other way, e.g. the *Close* button on the title bar. If not then your way is better, otherwise use the event. If the event is used, be sure to use it properly and don't prevent Windows shutting down or the like.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  The question is pretty vague, both options appear to be a possible choice. Btw, I put the closing bracket in the wrong place :)

Comment: @Jimi im getting a problem regardless if i choose yes or no it clears

Comment: @hunterisaacs, if it didn't work then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did then we can only guess what's wrong with it. If the parameters of the question have changed then change the question, i.e. edit your question to update it with the code you are now using.

Comment: I don't know what *im getting a problem* means, nor what *it clears* is referring to. You may want to take the time to better define your question. If you have a *problem* somewhere, you have to describe the problem (*I do >this<, I expect that something like >this< happens, instead it comes out like >this<*, where all the `>this<` parts are clearly exlpained).

Answer (score 1):

In your Form's closing event, you should initialize a MessageBox and check if the result from the dialog is not yes. If so, then cancel the event. Something along the lines of:

```
Public Sub MyForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyForm.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close the form?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) <> DialogResult.Yes Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I would have thought that there is already an example somewhere, and as it turns out there already is on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=netframework-4.8#examples

When in doubt, try to search the MSDN documentation. This is where I personally get 99% of my information.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the vagueness of this question as mentioned in the above comment and after reading numerous post about how to manage the titlebar X Close Button I thought I would expand on the above answer because I could not enter the line code e.Cancel = True
My problem was I could use this code on a form to navigate back to another form no problem
But when I wanted to ignore navigation and just leave the calling form showing nothing seemed to work the one line of code to note here is result = ""
While reading I also discovered code that would inactivate the X Close Button on the titlebar
As a BONUS I have included a KeyPress Event code that preforms Application.Exit

TitleBar X Close Button Code Below

```
    Private Sub frmOne_Closing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

    Const message As String = "YES Exit Progtam" + vbCrLf + vbNewLine + "NO CANCEL"
    Const caption As String = "EXIT"

    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        txtBoxOne.Text = "CANCEL"
        result = ""
        'Me.Hide() This Code Was Used On frmThree 
        'frmOne.Show()'To Navigate Back to frmOne
    End If
End Sub
```

KeyPress Event Code Below

```
    Public Sub frmOne_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    'frmOne Property KeyPreview needs to be set to True
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 27 Then
        'MessageBox.Show("You Pressed " & e.KeyChar)
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

Code to Inactivate the X Close Button

```
    'Private Const CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON As Integer = &H200
'Protected Overloads Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
'    Get
'        Dim myCp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
'        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle Or CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON
'        Return myCp
'    End Get
'    'This works but NOT what I want
'End Property
```